# How to show and hide div elements based on dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi i want to show and hide div elements according to the dropdown selection. I know this question has been asked a lot of time and i have tried the methods posted in the other question but to no avail. I want that on first selection the first div should only show and on second selection the first and second div both should show and so forth. I am unable to think of a jquery to do this.My code is as follows:-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("select").change(function(){
    $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
      if($(this).attr("value")=="one"){
        $(".subject").not(".one").hide();
        $(".one").show();
      }
      else if($(this).attr("value")=="two"){
        $(".subject").not(".two").hide();
        $(".two").show();
      }
      else{
        $(".subject").hide();
      }
    });
  }).change();
});
```

```css
.subject{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="subjects" id="select" class="form-control">
       <option value="">Number of Subjects</option>
       <option value="one">One</option>
       <option value="two">Two</option>
       <option value="three">Three</option>
    </select>

    <div class="one subject" id="one subject">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                 <label>Code</label>
                 <input type="text" name="scode1" class="form-control">
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
                 <label>Name</label>
                 <input type="text" name="sname1" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="two subject" id="two subject">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                 <label>Code</label>
                 <input type="text" name="scode2" class="form-control">
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
                 <label>Name</label>
                 <input type="text" name="sname2" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So if the user chooses the option value one then the div with one class should show up if he chooses option value two then both div one and two should show up and if nothing is selected it should not show anything. I have creating the javascript function it only shows single div not both i am unable to think of a way to show both.Any help would be highly appreciated. Javascript Code:-

Comment: Please write what have you tried?

Comment: `$('#select').on('change', function(){ $('#'+this.value).show() })`

Comment: Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/0p6b6srx/

Comment: Check out my answer.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi I have added the javascript function but it only shows one div not two when second option is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
$('#select').on('change', function(){ 
  $('.subject').hide();
  $('.'+this.value).show();
});
```

```css
.subject {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <select name="subjects" id="select" class="form-control">
       <option value="">Number of Subjects</option>
       <option value="one">One</option>
       <option value="two">Two</option>
       <option value="three">Three</option>
    </select>

    <div class="one two three subject" id="one">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                 <label>Code</label>
                 <input type="text" name="scode1" class="form-control">
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
                 <label>Name</label>
                 <input type="text" name="sname1" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="two three subject" id="two">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                 <label>Code</label>
                 <input type="text" name="scode2" class="form-control">
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
                 <label>Name</label>
                 <input type="text" name="sname2" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="three subject" id="three">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                 <label>Code</label>
                 <input type="text" name="scode2" class="form-control">
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
                 <label>Name</label>
                 <input type="text" name="sname2" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The function only shows one subject at a time i want when second option is selected it should show two code and two name fields.

Comment: Is this only work for 3 subject or more subject also??

Comment: @drosam If i add a button to submit then what class should i apply on its div tag so that it shows when any of the option is selected not when no value is selected.

Comment: You should apply the three classes and it will be shown when an option is selected

Answer (score 0):

I made a quick fiddle of your issue..
along with some alterations to Rayons comment.

https://jsfiddle.net/s237qaak/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#one, #two').hide();
  $('#select').on('change', function() {
    $('#one, #two').hide();
    $('#' + this.value).show()
  });

});
```

Comment: The function only shows one subject at a time i want when second option is selected it should show two code and two name fields.

Answer (score 0):

> Added a new class to each div's named `toggle` for hide all the div's.
>   And use the `this` to show only the selected div.

**JQuery:**

```
$('#select').on("change", function(){
    $(".toggle").css({ "display" : "none"} );
    var val = $(this).val();
    $("#"+val).css({ "display" : "block"} )
});
```

[Complete fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/frayne_konok/cbjg0ggb/)

Comment: the `toggle` is added for optimizing the work. It is in my fiddle and i added the note of it.

Comment: Yes, the note is what I was asking :)

Comment: @FrayneKonok  The function only shows one subject at a time i want when second option is selected it should show two code and two name fields.

Comment: So this is not the thing you are asking for? Okey let's see what is your desire output.

Answer (score 0):

try this Jquery Code. Also, add the class box to each of the divs(one,two)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#select").change(function(){
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            if($(this).attr("value")=="one"){
                $(".box").not(".one").hide();
                $(".one").show();
            }
            else if($(this).attr("value")=="two"){
                $(".box").not(".two").hide();
                $(".two").show();
            }
            else{
                $(".box").hide();
            }
        });
    }).change();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic is to

1. Hide all of the `div`s.
2. "listen" the select's changes using `.addEventListener('change')`.
3. When changed, get the value using `this.value`.
4. Again, hide all divs.
5. Show the selected div.

**To the code:**

```js
document.querySelector('#select').addEventListener('change', function(){
  //[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.panel'), function(el) {
  //  el.style.display = 'none';
  //});
  document.querySelector('#' + this.value).style.display = 'block';
  console.log(document.querySelector('#' + this.value));
});
```

```css
.panel {
  display:none;  
}
```

```html
<select name="subjects" id="select" class="form-control">
  <option value="">Number of Subjects</option>
  <option value="one">One</option>
  <option value="two">Two</option>
  <option value="three">Three</option>
</select>

<div class="one panel" id="one">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <label>Code</label>
      <input type="text" name="scode1" class="form-control" placeholder="scode1" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <label>Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="sname1" class="form-control" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="two panel" id="two">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <label>Code</label>
      <input type="text" name="scode2" class="form-control" placeholder="scode2" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <label>Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="sname2" class="form-control" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The function only shows one subject at a time i want when second option is selected it should show two code and two name fields.

Comment: OK, I was updated my answer. By the way, what about if you select `one`, then `two` then `one` again, what should happen?